# Node-webkit require is undefined

Tags: node-webkit, tiddlywiki

I'm trying to run the server version of TW5 as a node-webkit app. I followed the good instructions stated here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tiddlywiki/WRnhjD6LUPQ/Zmikdvo0QA0J

- to run those files in node-webkit, the code you need is here: https://gist.github.com/Arlen22/d7ad0b6a108fa3cedf72
- Open that link and copy index.htm and nodewebkit.js into the root of the tiddlywiki folder.
- Open package.json, and copy the two objects in the gist's package.json into it.
- Package.json already has a "main" object farther down which you will need to remove.
- Drag the entire tiddlywiki folder onto the node-webkit executable.

When I do the last step I got the following errors on the Developer tools console of node-webkit:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/.../node-webkit/TW5/index.htm data:text/html,chro…:1
```

The weird thing is: if I remove the index.html from the addres bar, then the TW5 folder is listed, and clicking on the index.html open the application as expected, working flawlessly. Could someone tell me where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at package.json. This is kind dumb, but I wrote index.htm instead of index.html. So if you are getting `Not allowed to load local resource:` error be sure to check your package.json for bad names.

Regards